# Merge Multiple Array Objects in While Loop then JSON Encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I'm trying to get, in result, one JSON string from a database of mine but the database returns multiple rows of data, that when JSON encoded, don't fit together with proper formatting.

My current PHP code

```
$conn = [omitted];
$sql = [omitted];
$result = $conn->query($sql); //this query has been proven to work
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $rows = [];
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $row[] = array_merge($row,$rows);
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
      } else {
          echo "0";
      }
```

But this code echos the `$rows` array before it's been merged with the `$row` arrays.

Current Result:

```
[]
```

Wanted Result:

```
[{"id":"1","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"2","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"3","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"4","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"5","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"6","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"},{"id":"7","team_name":"[omitted]","has_finished":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning any data into your $rows array.  To assign each row into the array you want this for your loop.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```